# 3D dataset and sklearn regression algorithms

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset similar to the image below.
[image]
How can I train one of the regression algorithms defined in the sklearn library using this dataset?

Comment: What does "Feature X" represent?  ... a class?  What regression model do you want?  I.e., what would you do with each "Feature" or each "Feature" component to predict the "Target"?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, Each "Feature X" shows the values of a metric over time, which are given here at five different times, for example in feature one [0.5, 3, 4, 6, 7].
Random Forest regression and ... .
Each "Feature"  in each row are used to predict the "Target" in the same row.

Comment: Why not just "explode" your 5 "Features" into 25 Features?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, Is there no other way?
This data set that I asked in this question is much smaller than the main data set that I have, for example, instead of 25 features, it has several hundred features.

Comment: Sure, there are lots and lots of ways. TBH, when I first saw your 5x5 data set I thought that it might represent something like a 2D image. You could implement a convolutional neural network if you wanted, though I don't know if that's appropriate. If the features are derived from some physical system (are they?), then I would expect that you perhaps have some model in mind.  I would also expect that "target" has some meaning that might suggest a model.  I also see that there are many repeats in the "Features" - might they represent classes, or perhaps your main dataset doesn't look like that.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, "there are lots and lots of way". Is there a specific source that explains these ways?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, Thanks for the comment you wrote. In fact, my features are metrics such as IPC, Occupancy and etc, that are obtained when a kernel is executed on a GPU. These metrics are obtained during the kernel execution time on the GPU.

Comment: Since your question isn't directly about programming, perhaps it would be better asked [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).